# Why can we not initialize instance variable in two steps like

Tags: java, variables, initialization, instance

```
class A {
    int n;
    n=1;
}
```

Error: identifier expected pointing n=1;

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `n=1;` can only appear in a method/constructor/initialization block.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know about you're asking.... Eran is right !

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code with int n = 1;

And this question seems to be the duplicate of [Java instance variable declare and Initialize in two statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694197/java-instance-variable-declare-and-initialize-in-two-statements?rq=1).

I don't have enough privileges, someone with the privileges, please label it as 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as already pointed in other answers is:
writing `int n =1;` as single line.

But if you want to understand the reason for this error, it is that you cannot have statements inside the class body. Statements can only be inside methods/constructors/initialization blocks as @Eran pointed out.

When you do 
`int n = 1;` 
in single line, it's a special statement/expression and is called **definition**. So it's allowed as a special case.

Read more about statements and expressions here: [JAVA statements and expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

However, this is possible:

```
public class A{
    int n;
    {
       n = 1;
    }
}
```