# How to define Map contents on initialisation?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, initialization

I was just wondering if it is possible to define the contents of a Map Object on initialisation.

For example, an array can be created, as:

```
new String[] {“apples”, “bananas”, “pears”}
```

So, I was wondering if there is something similar we can do for maps.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-to-initialise-a-static-map-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can, sort of, using this syntax trick:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>() {{
    put("x", "y");
    put("a", "b");
}};
```

Not very pleasant, though.  This creates an anonymous subclass of `HashMap`, and populates it in the instance initializer.

Comment: Nice trick. I'd put those inner {}s on separate lines, though, as it looks very confusing right now.

Comment: @Sergey: Sure, whatever style you prefer. I've always used this style, though, and whenever I see this trick used, it also uses this style. You get used to it. The important thing is the initializer, that's what should be focussed on.

Comment: Well, it's the first time I see this trick, I guess that explains confusion.

Comment: This is a really bad practice: it causes a reference to the current object to be leaked. I wish I could vote down but I cannot just yet.

Comment: Thanks for the warning @AndreaRatto - to those wanting more info on why: it is because the new object `map` contains an implicit `this` object referencing the parent object. More info here: https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/

Comment: The builder solution is better but @AndreaRatto, I hate myself for even suggesting it, but couldn't you immediately create a normal HashMap from the leaking version to release the leak?  `new HashMap<String,String>(new HashMap<String,String>() {{put("x", "y");    put("a", "b");}});`

Answer (score 16):

If your `Map` is going to be immutable after creation and you don't mind adding a dependency, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) offers some nice fluent [syntax](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html):

```
Map<K,V> aMap = ImmutableMap.<K,V>builder().put(key0, val0).put(key1,val1).build();
```

If you're feeling really exotic, [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) has syntax exactly like what you want and is interoperable with other Java code:

```
val aMap = Map("a"->0, "b"->1)
```

Note that the Scala compiler will infer the `Map` generic type is from `String` to `Int`, based on what you put in it, though you can explicitly specify it as well.

However, if this is just a one-off, I'd go with the initializer-based syntax.  Both the Guava library and Scala language have a lot else to recommend them, but learning a whole new library/language might be overboard.

Comment: +1 for the Scala reference :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use initializer blocks:

```
class Foo {
   //using static initializer block 
   static Map<String,String> m1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
   static {
      m1.put("x","y");
      m1.put("a","b");
   }    

   //using initializer block 
   Map<String,String> m2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
   {
      m2.put("x","y");
      m2.put("a","b");
   }    

}
```

Comment: Someone pointed out to me once that using instance initializers instead of constructors is a bad idea, particularly because it makes exception handling more difficult. static initializers are fine, though.

Comment: @Sergey: Depends. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355810/how-is-an-instance-initializer-different-from-a-constructor

Comment: I wouldn't put error-prone code in initializers, but for safe operations like filling collections I see no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Something very hacky..can be improved, but this is just a direction:
Define a static helper to convert an object array to a map of this type:

```
    public static<K,V> Map<K, V> fromArray(Object[] anObjArray){
    int size = anObjArray.length;
    Map<K, V> aMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (int i=0;i<=size/2;i=i+2){
        K key = (K)anObjArray[i];
        V value = (V)anObjArray[i+1];
        aMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return aMap;
}
```

then you can create a map using this:

```
        Map<Integer, String> aMap = MapUtils.<Integer, String>fromArray(new Object[]{1, "one", 2,"two"});
```

I would personally second Gauva builder suggestion from @Carl though :-)