# Constructor vs Curly Brackets (?)

Tags: java, eclipse

While searching for a way to define static constructors, I've stumbled upon the use of the following:

```
class MyClass {
    { /* code for constructor-like (?) effect */ }
}
```

Basically the code that is entered in curly brackets directly in the class works, as far as I can see, exactly the same as a code in a constructor - except that it is called **before** the constructor.

What is the purpose of this, and are there other differences between this and a standard constructor?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't get confused with the curly brackets. Those are not necessary.

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan: Nope; they are, otherwise you can't get "code with constructor like effect". For e.g. catching exceptions etc.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: Ok, they are called before constructor, so I would not call it "constructor like" effect.
If you omit the curly brackets, you cannot catch excpetions, but aren't the calling time and result same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block with the curly brackets is an instance initializer block. [This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) from Oracle's Java Tutorials has some more info about it.

Also see: [How is an instance initializer different from a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355810/how-is-an-instance-initializer-different-from-a-constructor)

Answer (score 8):

Those are called [instance initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). The details can be found in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355810/how-is-an-instance-initializer-different-from-a-constructor).

Comment: Thanks. (Exactly same answer as Jesper, but he answered first so I have to give him the accepted answer)