# Why is it illegal to assign a class variable that was just declared?

Tags: java, class, oop

```
class A {
    public int someVar;
    someVar = 123;      /* cannot find symbol */
}
```

Why cant the language see the variable I just declared? And is this unique to Java or this is true in all classful OOP languages?

Comment: Class bodies cannot contain executable code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no, false; you could write `public Foo foo = new Foo()`, and the constructor contains arbitrary code.

Comment: @djechlin That's an instance initialization statement. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/instance-variable-initialization-in-java). It's not the same as executable code.

Comment: @djechlin That is object initialization

Comment: so is this unique to Java or this applies to all OOP languages?

Comment: @Photon object initialization is executable code.

Comment: @1der It's likely on a per-language basis, but note that python doesn't allow you to put code outside the methods at all. You must define them all with self.variable. They may also be defined outside of the constructor for the first time for a class.

Every language does OO differently

Answer (score 9):

In Java, you can declare instance variables inside a class but outside a method, but statements such as `someVar = 123;` must be within a method (or a constructor, a static initializer, or an instance initializer).

Comment: +1, but will add that they may also be within an initialization block

Comment: @Kon Yes, I've added to my answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have arbitrary statements in a class definition. You can either immediately assign the variable in the declaration:

```
public int someVar = 123;
```

Or, assign it in a constructor or other instance scope:

```
public class A {
  public int someVar;

  public A() {
    someVar = 123;
  }
}
//Or...
public class B {
  public int someVar;
  { someVar = 123; }
}
```

Note that the second technique uses an [instance initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355810/how-is-an-instance-initializer-different-from-a-constructor), which is not always the most immediately clear piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can not declare `someVar = 123;` statement directly in class.
It should be `instance` block or `in method` or in `constructor`

```
 class A {
    public int someVar = 123;
}
```

or

```
class A {

    public int someVar ;
    {
          somevar = 123;
    }
}
```

or

```
class A {

        public int someVar ;
        A(){
              somevar = 123;
        }
    }
```

or

```
class A {

        public int someVar ;
        public void method(){
              somevar = 123;
        }
    }
```

Comment: or `public int somevar = 123;`

Answer (score 1):

But, oddly, you can code

```
public class AFunnyClass {
    public int someVar;
    {
        someVar = 123;
    }
    public static int anotherVar;
    static {
        anotherVar = 456;
    }
    public int yetAnotherVar = 789;
    public static int adNauseum = 101112;
}
```

Comment: Yes, using an instance initializer and a static initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `someVar` as a static variable.
Then you should declare it also static. Using it like:

```
class A {
    static public int someVar = 123; 
}
```

That means someVar isn't just a member of an instance of this Class, it becomes a member of the class it self. That also means `someVar` will be instantiated just once and can be used by all instances of this Class