# Why use a static declaration when initializing a new non-static object

Tags: java, static, initialization

I apologize if this is redundant, but I was not able to find a similar question. And, TBH, I don't even know how to frame the question properly.

This is a from a review question from the Java 8 OCA study guide. The question is about static initializers, which I understand just fine. There is however a line of code that I don't get, and because the question isn't about it, there is not a very good explanation of it.

```
private static Rope rope = new Rope();
```

So this isn't about Singletons or static classes. I don't understand why you would initialize an object like this. And, if there is a good reason why you can and would do this, what is the reason?

Would someone kindly point me in the direction of an explanation? Like I said, I'm not even sure what this is properly called, so am having a hard time finding a good answer on my own.

---

Edit to put in the entire class:

```
import rope.*;
import static rope.Rope.*;

public class RopeSwing
{
  private static Rope rope1 = new Rope("rope 1");
  private static Rope rope2 = new Rope("rope 2");

  {
    System.out.println(rope1.length);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    rope1.length = 2;
    rope2.length = 8;
    System.out.println(rope1.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: `rope` is not a 'non-static object'. The fact that `Rope` isn't a static class is irrelevant.

Comment: I removed the line about `Rope` not being a "static class", since people seem to be getting hung up on that fact. It's an understandable confusion, but not related to the syntax you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes a single `Rope` instance available to the whole class - it will be shared by all instances of the class this is declared in. This can be useful when there's some shared information or state all instances should rely on.

Often, `private static` fields are also declare `final`, which makes them [constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) (assuming the type of the field is immutable). Looking at your full example, I suspect the author should have made them `private static final`.

For example:

```
public class Foo {
  private static Rope rope = new Rope();
  private int value;

  public Foo(int value) { this.value = value; }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "static rope: " + rope + " instance value: " + value;
  }
}
```

If you create several instances of `Foo` (`new Foo(1);`, '`new Foo(2)`, etc.) they will all share the same `rope` instance, and `new Rope()` will only have been invoked once (when the class is first loaded).

---

An example of a non-constant static field might be a shared counter. Suppse you want to uniquely identify every instance of an object that gets constructed, anywhere in your application. You can do so with an `AtomicInteger`, which is essentially a thread-safe `int`:

```
public class Unique {
  // despite being final this is not a "constant" because it's mutable
  private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
  private final int id;

  public Unique() {
    id = counter.getAndIncrement();
  }

  @Override public String toString() { return "ID: " + id; }
}
```

Give it a try - every instance of `Unique` will have a unique ID.

---

In your example code there's an [instance initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1355810/113632), which will be invoked when creating a new instance (hence after the `static` fields have been initialized).

Comment: Let me say that back at you to make sure I get it: Because the initializer is declared static, it can be accessed without an instance of the class it's written in being constructed.

Comment: Well, sort of. Because the *field* is declared static it will be initialized when the class is first loaded, before any instances of the class are constructed. But because it's `private` nothing can *access* the field except instances of the class defining the `private static` field.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thank you. I believe I'm getting it now. Thanks for the help. The test review questions are full of "Gotcha" code like that that just leaves me scratching my head.